# How to implement a popover on a form field in a View (bootstrap-saas)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a popover on a form field in a Rails View, using the `bootstrap-saas` gem.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>

  <div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :fname, "First Name", :class => "control-label" %>

    <div class="controls">
  <%= f.text_field :fname, class: "input-large", rel: "popover", :"data-content"=>"Enter First Name" %>
</div>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

What am I missing with this?

Comment: Are you using JS to actually turn on the popover? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Comment: Didn't know I needed to do this with popover. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn on the popover. The most common way is to give the popover a class, and use JS (my example will be with jQuery) to turn it on.

```
# view
# ...
<%= f.text_field :fname, class: "input-large popover-input", rel: "popover", :"data-content"=>"Enter First Name" %>
```

(Note the additional class name of `popover-input`. Call it whatever you'd like.)

```
# JS
# ...
$(".popover-input").popover();
```

And voila!

The [Bootstrap page for Popovers](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) shows additional options you can use for popovers.

Comment: Where is the best place to put this code: `$(".popover-input").popover();` - in the users.js.coffee file? I've done this, and the page renders with no popover functionality. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could put it in users.js.coffee, sure, but then you'd have to make sure that that file was being included on your page. That's the main thing: your JS has to be included for it to be run.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new js file on assets/javascript/**custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".popover-input").popover();
});
```